# want to change UINavigationBar title Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have set UINavigationBar title for a particular rootViewController only. I Have wrote below code in that VC's viewWillAppear method, and I have also set the defaults for the next viewController. I am getting "Zapfino" fonts but, The problem is when I press "back" from next VC, I get the default title font for the root VC.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 18)!]
```

Comment: I used this code `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 18)!]` and it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your next viewController when you when you set default font, In that file you need to again set the particular root ViewController font in view will disappears method for next viewController . so you can get you font back.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "System", size: 12.0)!]
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "System", size: 17.0)!]
}
```